# Read from property file in entity

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have an attribute expiryDate in my entity. i want when i ceate an instance from this entity, i set the value of the attribute expiryDate. The value is in the application.yml file. I used `Properties.getProperty` in the construct but it didn't work

application.yml:

```
application:
  token:
    expiredIn: 1440
```

Token entity:

```
public abstract class Token implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private UUID id;

    private int expiryIn;

    public Token() {
        this.expiryIn= Properties.getProperty("application.token.expiredIn");
    }

}
```

**#UPDATE**

I used `@Value` but the value of expiration is always 0

```
public abstract class Token implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private Date expiryDate;

    @Value("${application.token.expiredIn}")
    private static int expiration;

    public Token() {
        this.expiryDate = calculateExpiryDate(expiration);
    }

    private Date calculateExpiryDate(final int expiryTimeInMinutes) {
        final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTimeInMillis(new Date().getTime());
        cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, expiryTimeInMinutes);
        return new Date(cal.getTime().getTime());
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure it´s the correct path? And I would use the `@Value("${myProperties.property}")` annotation for this.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
   public abstract class Token implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private UUID id;

    @Value("${application.token.expiredIn}")
    private int expiryIn;


}
```

`@Value` will take the value from `application.yml` file and inject it into `expiryIn`.